# How to show BASE64 stored data in SQL Server in an Image in WebForms ASP.NET - RDLC report

Tags: c#, asp.net, rdlc

I've Asset Codes which I'm converting into BASE64 like this:

```
private string GenerateBarcode(string BarCode)
{
    string generatebarcode = BarCode;

    GeneratedBarcode barcode = BarcodeWriter.CreateBarcode(generatebarcode, BarcodeWriterEncoding.Code128);

    barcode.ResizeTo(400, 120);
    barcode.SetMargins(10);
    barcode.ChangeBarCodeColor(Color.Black);

    Image MyBarCodeImage = barcode.Image;

    var myArray = (byte[])new ImageConverter().ConvertTo(MyBarCodeImage, typeof(byte[]));
    string temp_inBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(myArray);

    return temp_inBase64;
}
```

And after this, I'm saving this BASE64 into my database.

Now, getting this into my Dataset, showing in tabular form.

At the RDLC level, I've tried:

- Drop an Image report control from toolbox.
- Right click on the image and choose image properties
- Set the image source to database
- Set the MIME type to a suitable value, for example image/bmp.
- Set use this field to the image value which you have,

For example `=Fields!Code.Value`. The parameter type should be Text.

But it's not showing anything in the RDLC Report Viewer.

I've found many solutions on the internet but none of them seems works to me. Is there something that I missed?

I use Visual Studio 2019 Community, .NET Framework 4.7.2, `Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms` 15.0.0.0

Thanks.

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to display a barcode image that had bytes converted to base 64 as an image. I bet you need to decode the image prior to binding the value in the report.

Comment: You may be able to get this to work -> =System.Convert.FromBase64String()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you consider storing the data in the table as raw binary, and then convert to base64 as required.

the bonus points is that the RDLC can and will accpet a raw binay data source for a image.

So, example with raw binary, gridview, and RDLC report example.

So, say I have this gridView, and I need to display that binary picture:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" 
    runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ID"
    CssClass="table" Width="50%" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound"
    >
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Fighter" HeaderText="Fighter"        />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Engine"  HeaderText="Engine"         />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Thrust"  HeaderText="Thrust (lbs)"   />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstFlight" HeaderText="First Flight"
            DataFormatString ="{0:MM dd yyyy}"  ItemStyle-Width="100"    />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description"    />
        <asp:TemplateField ControlStyle-Width="132">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server"/>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

And my code to load - along with the "binary" convert in the row data bound event.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            LoadGrid();
    }

    void LoadGrid()
    {
        string strSQL =
            @"SELECT ID, Fighter,Engine, Thrust, FirstFlight, Description, MyImage
            FROM Fighters ORDER BY Thrust";

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL, conn))
            {
                conn.Open();
                DataTable rstData = new DataTable();
                rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());
                GridView1.DataSource = rstData;
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }

    protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            DataRowView gData = e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView;
            Image MyImage = e.Row.FindControl("Image1") as Image;

            MyImage.ImageUrl =
                @"data:image/jpeg;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])gData["MyImage"]);
        }
    }
```

And now I see/get this:

[image]

So, in above, I CONVERT on the fly the raw binary data in the SQL table to base64 string.

And creating a RDLC report, this also works

[image]

Then I can indeed bind the image control directly to the image column, and the column and it works

eg:

[image]

and then when I run this, I get this:

[image]

however, if you stroring the picture as a base64 string?

You only need to "exclude" the first of the string with the mine type, and only include everything after the "," in the base64 string should work.

eg this:
=Convert.FromBase64String(CStr(Parameters!Base64.Value).Substring(22))

You have to change the 22 based on the type of image.

So, in my case, I'm using/testing with a jpeg.

thus this:

```
 data:image/jpeg;base64,/
```

So, my expression to chop all off up to the "," is thus this:

[image]

So this works for me:

```
=Convert.FromBase64String(CStr(Fields!MyImage2.Value).Substring(23))
```

So, you CAN use a base64 string. It just that you are NOT to include the first part (mine type info) in that string.

If you don't want to change this in the report viewer, then I suppose you could add/make/have/create a expression in the sql to only return all characters after 23 chars.

Comment: tried this all, still unable to to display the Image that's already saved in Database as Base64 string. Moreover, I'm not getting any Base64 which is having ",".

Comment: Albert, 100 % marks for your efforts BTW. Thanks Pal

Comment: As I stated the image may or may not include the mine header for first 20 chars or so. If it don't then YOU have to put/add/have that header part on a web page, but for report viewer you don't.  So do the pictures work in/on/with a web page?You also need that header part if you are doing this  on a web page.  So both a simple image control  on a web page or using report viewer will and should work - above shows both code examples and thus both work

Comment: That link does not work for me. You are MUCH better off to setup a test web page, and feed the image that image, and see if the image works. If you can't get a simple image control dropped into a test web page to work, then FOR SURE it not going to work inside of a RDL report. So, paste a image (hopefully a small one) into notepad.txt, and then write a few lines of code to read that file, and shove it into a image. if it does not render, then we are probably missing the header information. However, as noted, the report writer does not require the mine/header, but web pages do.

Comment: So, if the image is small (not long), then edit your post and add a simple base64 string to your post, and we can try and see if it works. However, that sample link in your comments here does not resolve to anything and does not seem to produce/return from that web link any kind of valid image.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using webforms, you can use the asp Image control

```cs
<asp:Image ID="ImageObject" runat="server" Width="400"/>
```

And from server side do something like this

```cs
public void SetImageData(byte[] inArray)
    {
        string strBase64Logo = Convert.ToBase64String(inArray);
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(strBase64Logo))
        {
            ImageObject.Visible = true;
            ImageObject.ImageUrl = "data:Image/png;base64," + strBase64Logo;
        }
        else
        {
            ImageObject.Visible = false;
        }
            
    }
```

Save (and load) your image info as `byte[]` and let the control know that you will use an image from Base64 as `data:Image/png;base64`.

Just a heads-up: if you are storing your images as base64 in database, **it will grow a lot really fast**, and there will be network overhead when retrieving multiple images from database and when sending them to the page. I had a project with exactly this scenario and we found out that it was slow to load multiple images at the same time, as the queries returned a lot of data just from the images.

Comment: he specific stated and noted he is using RDL (Report Definition Language).  While even as my exmaple shows, the real advantage of reports is they perfect render to PDF, word, and and even Excel - with perfect formatting. And printing works absoulte amazing. And those reports are also how SQL server reporting services works. So, your suggesting will only work if one dumps the use of the report writer. And while we all agree 100% that using a image path is far better, these reports can be run from SQL server reporting services - and no path name to images exist as a result.

Comment: Edit: As a follow up and FYI? Turns out the RDL report writer DOES work, but you are NOT to send the mine/header to the report. If you remove/skip/don't have the mine header (the data:Image/pgn;base64 part), then the reporting services report writer DOES work and WILL render base 64 strings. One of course has to set the correct image time in the report writer's image control settings, but once done, then it does accept and render base64 images - you just have to skip/remove the mine header part.